# Segment "xxx" which is not a keyword for a postVarSet as expected on page

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x, realurl

I get the folllowing error in typo3 when I click a button in subpage3(Page Id=13).

```
Page Not Found
Reason: Segment "xxx" was not a keyword for a postVarSet as expected on 
page with id=10.
```

This is the structure of my page tree

```
id=0
|id=10 
-|id=11 (subpage1)
-|id=12 (subpage2)
-|id=13 (subpage3)
```

Hope somebody can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the link that is called by the button, can be without the domain

Comment: if($this->request->hasArgument('btnRegister')){
            $lastinsertedId = $this->RegistrationRepository->registerUser($user);
        }                                                                                                                          this is the code in button.It only contain an insert query.

Comment: That's php-code and therefore on the server-side. Important is what is happening when the button is clicked on client-side. Which URL is called?

Comment: And if the code is shown in the frontend (the produced website you see in the browser) then something with your template or setup is wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question to include all required details. Thanks!